# Modifying InnerHTML breaks button

Tags: javascript

I am creating a table with variable amount of rows. On creation of the table, I also want to add in a button that calculates something with the data entered into the created table.

```js
const go = document.querySelector("#go");
const table = document.querySelector("#table");

go.addEventListener('click',(event) => {
    const n = document.querySelector("#n").value;
    console.log(n);
    let calc = document.createElement('button');
    calc.className = "calc";
    calc.textContent = "calculate";
    table.appendChild(calc);
  
    table.innerHTML += "<div class='break'></div>";
    /* 
    ----Other elements added using innerHTML----
    */

    calc.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("Test");
    })

});
```

```html
Enter value of N:
<input type="text" id="n">
<button id="go">go</button>
<br>
<div id="table"></div>
```

The problem I am facing is if I add anything to the innerHTML of table div, The button stops working. The above button stops working if  `//table.innerHTML += "<div class='break'></div>";` is uncommented. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: There are a variety of other duplicates available.  Essentially when you *overwrite* `innerHTML` then you replace the existing contents with new contents.  Any event handlers that were attached to the old contents are lost when those old contents are discarded, and new event listeners would need to be added to the new contents.  In your specific scenario, just continue to use `createElement` and `appendChild` as you did with the button.

Comment: I would suggest being consistent with how you are adding elements to `table`; you created `calc` with `document.createElement()` and appending it to `table`. Rather than using `innerHTML` to add your div, use `document.createElement()` again and append it to table.